# Scraping just the <p> without the embedded <a>

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the body of this article: 
https://www.cnbc.com/2017/12/07/pinterest-hires-former-facebook-exec-gary-johnson-to-run-corporate-dev.html

This would normally be a very simple find_all('p') but I am having some trouble avoiding the (a) that lies inside some of the (p). For instance, this occurs when a word in the body is hyperlinked to another URL

I would like to get just the text, without the URL. So far I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get("https://www.cnbc.com/2017/12/07/pinterest-hires-former-facebook-exec-gary-johnson-to-run-corporate-dev.html").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

all_paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
```

How could I extract just the text from all the (p) without the (a) and ensuing URL?

Thank you in advance

Comment: [extrac()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) removes elements  - so remove `a` and you get only `p`

Comment: or maybe you need `item.text` or `item.get_text()`

Comment: Take a look at a certain portion of `p` tag: `he'll be replaced by [Google] veteran Jon Alferness`. In this portion `Google` is within `a` tag and without which the sentence is unclear. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

To get all text inside `p` (even from `a`) but without those tags use `.text` or `.get_text()`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get("https://www.cnbc.com/2017/12/07/pinterest-hires-former-facebook-exec-gary-johnson-to-run-corporate-dev.html").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

all_paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')

for p in all_paragraphs:
    #print(p) # all HTML
    print(p.get_text()) # p.get_text(strip=True)
    # or
    print(p.text)
```

If you want `p` without text in `a` then you have to remove `a` before you get text

```
for p in all_paragraphs:
    for a in p.find_all('a'):
       a.extract()
    print(p.text)
```